# Laravel Eloquent : Count data from two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have two different tables named `artists` and `artworks`. I want to retrieve data from both tables and show them in `Summary` table.

**Condition here is** : get `name` (there are other columns in this table) from `artists` table and get the `number of total artworks` from `artworks` table. Show them in `Summary` table.

```
artists
|-------------------|
|  id   |   name    |
|-------------------|
|  1    |    A      |
|-------------------|
|  2    |    B      |
|-------------------|
|  3    |    C      |
|-------------------|

artworks
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  id   |   artist_id   |   title   |     medium      |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |       1       |    ABC    |      Oil        |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |       1       |    DEF    |     Water       |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |       1       |    GHI    |     Water       |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |       2       |    JKL    |      Oil        |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |       2       |    MNO    |     Water       |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |       3       |    PQR    |      Oil        |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
```

This is what I want:

```
Summary
|-------------------------------------------|
|  No   |   Artist Name  |   Total Artwork  |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  1    |        A       |         3        |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  2    |        B       |         2        |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  3    |        C       |         1        |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you added a relationship in the model? or you want to use a DB query?

Comment: No, there's no relation. DB query will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you want to use DB query then you need to add join.

```
\DB::table('artists')
->join('artworks', 'artists.id', '=', 'artworks.artist_id')
->select('artists.id as id', 'artists.name as name', \DB::raw("count(artworks.artist_id) as count"))
->groupBy('artists.id')
->get();
```

And if you want to use Relation then use `hasMany`  relation in **Artist** model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artist extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'artists';

    public function artworks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Artwork','artist_id','id');
    }
}
```

In controller

```
$artists = Artist::withCount('artworks')->get();
foreach($artists as $artist) {
    echo $artist->artworks_count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed the second approach as it looks more efficient. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method on your relationship:

```php
$artists = Artist::withCount('artworks')->get();
foreach($artists as $artist) {
    echo $artist->artworks_count;
}
```

Comment: this requires key relationship between two tables, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `hasMany` relation in Artist model.

Comment: @TariqulIslam Yes. You already have the table schematics enabled for it, so you just have to add the relationship references to your models.